# asynchronous subprocess with Popen

Tags: python, asynchronous, multiprocessing, subprocess, executable

Using Windows 7 + python 2.6, I am trying to run a simulation model in parallel. I can launch multiple instances of the executable by double-clicking on them in my file browser. However, asynchronous calls with `Popen` result in each successive instance interrupting the previous one. For what it's worth, the executable returns text to the console, but I don't need to collect results interactively.

Here's where I am so far:

```
import multiprocessing, subprocess

def run(c):
    exe = os.path.join("<location>","folder",str(c),"program.exe")
    run = os.path.join("<location>","folder",str(c),"run.dat")
    subprocess.Popen([exe,run],creationflags = subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)

def main():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(3)
    for c in range(10):
        pool.apply_async(run,(str(c),))
 pool.close()
 pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

After scouring SO for a solution, I've learned that using multiprocessing may be redundant, but I need some way to limit the number of cores working.

Comment: Have you tried to specify different working directories for each subprocess using `cwd` argument? The `exe` probably writes some files to current directory that interferes with parallel execution.

Comment: you could use `os.path.join` to join path parts instead of direct string manipulation

Comment: Popen returns immediately so your script doesn't limit number of parallel subprocesses. You could use `subprocess.call()` to block until the subprocess finishes.

Comment: `os.path.join`, yes, of course. updated.

Comment: [this answer demonstrates various techniques to limit number of concurrent subprocesses](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9874484/4279): it shows `multiprocessing.Pool`, `concurrent.futures`, `threading + Queue` -based solutions

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Specifying `cwd` does the trick. I missed that important part in your thorough treatment of the subject, linked above. Please post as an answer.

Comment: post your solution as an answer. It is explicitly encouraged. Better to post code that was tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabled by @J.F. Sebastian's comment regarding the `cwd` argument.

```
import multiprocessing, subprocess

def run(c):
    exe = os.path.join("<location>","folder",str(c),"program.exe")
    run = os.path.join("<location>","folder",str(c),"run.dat")
    subprocess.check_call([exe,run],cwd=os.path.join("<location>","folder"),creationflags = subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)

def main():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(3)
    for c in range(10):
        pool.apply_async(run,(str(c),))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: btw, there is `mutiprocessing.dummy.Pool`  that provides the same interface but uses threads instead of processes that might be more appropriate in this case.