# Keep a variable number of subprocesses constantly running

Tags: python, list, subprocess

I'm planning a list of subprocesses of *some.exe* e.g.

```
max_processes = 4
proc_list = []
for i in range(100):
    while len(proc_list) <= max_processes:
        proc_list.append(subprocess.Popen(["some.exe", i]))
```

The processes should work in the *background* and the number of *max_processes* should constantly run. The std out of *some.exe* is not required.

This is a rough plan of what I'd like to do, is this even possible or do I have to rethink the whole concept?

Comment: related: [Python threading multiple bash subprocesses?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14533458/4279)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) or `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
# OR  from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool
import subprocess

def run_some_exe(i):
    subprocess.call(['some.exe', i])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    max_processes = 4
    pool = Pool(max_processes)
    pool.map(run_some_exe, range(100))
```

[`mulitprocess.Pool.map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map) works like [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) except that it run the function parallelly. (max 4 in above example)

Comment: thank you very much for the suggestions, how would I accomplish the `pool.map(lambda [...]` if I'd have to determine the `i` on another way - say `if some_var = False: i = some_list[j]`. Am I correct to say that I could wrap a `while some_bool:` around the `pool.map[...]` and assign `i` each time and call `pool.map(subprocess.call(['some.exe', i]))`. Would i have *some.exe* running 4 times, all the time - until *some_bool* becomes False?

Comment: Note that this isn't going to work on Windows, because of the use of a lambda inside the `if __name__ == "__main__"` guard. You'll need to use a top-level function outside the guard, instead.

Comment: @dano, Thank you for the comment. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @DaedalusMythos, I updated the answer to use a function instead of a lambda. For your case, I would make a shared list for all processes, and use it in the `run_some_exe` function. (BTW, note that I used `subprocess.call` instead of `subprocess.Popen` to make each process wait the termination of the `some.exe`)

Comment: One other note: It actually might make more sense to use `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` for this, since we don't actually need the separate processes to avoid the GIL.

Comment: @dano, updated the answer again to add that. Thank you.

Comment: thanks a lot for the update, looks almost like what I had in mind. If i issue `pool.map(run_some_exe)` in a `while a_boolean:`, where i declare `i` in the run_some_exe, will it keep 4 processes up until `a_boolean` is false?

Comment: @DaedalusMythos, The works to do is not fixed beforehand?  like `range(100)` in `pool.map(run_some_exe, range(100))`

Comment: @falsetru the `i` which I put simply as `i in range(100)` is actually a value in a database, which is queried before assigned to a *some.exe*..

Comment: @DaedalusMythos, Then, replace the `range(100)` with the list of the values fetched.

Comment: @falsetru of course can I use the list there, but unfortunately do I have to set a bit in the database for each successfully processed `i` by *some.exe* (which might crash). You pointed me in the right direction - which helps a lot :) thank you

Comment: @DaedalusMythos, You have a function `run_some_exe`. Do whatever you want there :)

Comment: haha you're right.. But still can I `while a_boolean: pool.map(run_some_exe)` to keep the 4 *threads/processes/whatever* running until `a_boolean` is False?

Comment: @DaedalusMythos, Yes you can do it. But it will create 4 processes (threads) inside the loop; and wait for them to finish jobs.

Comment: Will it wait as soon as I call the `run_some_exe` function (e.g. `run_some_exe` - wait until it's finished, then start the next `run_some_exe`) or will it create 4, wait until *one* is finished and then start a new one - repeating until above mentioned boolean is False?

Comment: @DaedalusMythos, the latter.

Comment: you could use a thread pool instead of process pool. Change import to `multiprocessing.dummy`.