# How does Python's subprocess and multiprocessing packages interoperate?

Tags: python, subprocess, python-multiprocessing

I want to use multiprocessing to spread work across a system's multiple cores. As part of the work, they will run `subprocess.call(..., shell=True)`. What happens when they do that? Does the subprocess fork stay on that core?

Comment: Did you try it? Usually, new processes are scheduled by the OS.

Comment: Probably not.  You usually have to explicitly bind processes to core.  The method to do this is OS-dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the main work is done in the child processes created using `subprocess` module then you don't need `multiprocessing` to spread the work across multiple CPU cores. See [Python threading multiple bash subprocesses?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14533458/4279)

> What happens when they do that?

`subprocess.call()` runs an external command and waits for it to complete. It doesn't matter whether it is started inside a worker process created by `multiprocessing` module or not.

> Does the subprocess fork stay on that core?

If you need it; you should set CPU affinity explicitly. [`psutil` provides a portable way to set/get CPU affinity for a process](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/index.html#psutil.Process.cpu_affinity).

If you use `numpy` then it may affect the cpu affinity. See [Why does multiprocessing use only a single core after I import numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15639779/4279)

Comment: Thanks for the detail.