# Multiple Processes - Python

Tags: windows, multithreading, python-2.7

I am looking to run multiple instances of a command line script at the same time. I am new to this concept of "multi-threading" so am at bit of a loss as to why I am seeing the things that I am seeing.

I have tried to execute the sub-processing in two different ways:

1 - Using multiple calls of Popen without a communicate until the end:

```
command = 'raster2pgsql -I -C -e -s 26911 %s -t 100x100 -F p839.%s_image_sum_sum1 | psql -U david -d projects -h pg3' % (workspace + '\\r_sumsum1{}'.format(i), str(i))

process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

command = 'raster2pgsql -I -C -e -s 26911 %s -t 100x100 -F p839.%s_image_sum_sum2 | psql -U david -d projects -h pg3' % (workspace + '\\r_sumsum2{}'.format(i), str(i))

process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

command = 'raster2pgsql -I -C -e -s 26911 %s -t 100x100 -F p839.%s_image_sum_sum3 | psql -U david -d projects -h pg3' % (workspace + '\\r_sumsum3{}'.format(i), str(i))

process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

(stdoutdata, stderrdata) = process.communicate()
```

this starts up each of the command line item but only completes the last entry leaving the other 2 hanging.

2 - Attempting to implement an example from [Python threading multiple bash subprocesses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14533458/python-threading-multiple-bash-subprocesses) but nothing happens except for a printout of the commands (program hangs with no command line arguments running as observed in windows task manager:

```
import threading
import Queue
import commands
import time

workspace = r'F:\Processing\SM'
image = 't08r_e'
image_name = (image.split('.'))[0]
i = 0
process_image_tif = workspace + '\\{}{}.tif'.format((image.split('r'))[0], str(i))

# thread class to run a command
class ExampleThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, cmd, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.cmd = cmd
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        # execute the command, queue the result
        (status, output) = commands.getstatusoutput(self.cmd)
        self.queue.put((self.cmd, output, status))

# queue where results are placed
result_queue = Queue.Queue()

# define the commands to be run in parallel, run them
cmds = ['raster2pgsql -I -C -e -s 26911 %s -t 100x100 -F p839.%s_image_sum_sum1 | psql -U david -d projects -h pg3' % (workspace + '\\r_sumsum1{}'.format(i), str(i)),
        'raster2pgsql -I -C -e -s 26911 %s -t 100x100 -F p839.%s_image_sum_sum2 | psql -U david -d projects -h pg3' % (workspace + '\\r_sumsum2{}'.format(i), str(i)),
        'raster2pgsql -I -C -e -s 26911 %s -t 100x100 -F p839.%s_image_sum_sum3 | psql -U david -d projects -h pg3' % (workspace + '\\r_sumsum3{}'.format(i), str(i)),

       ]
for cmd in cmds:
    thread = ExampleThread(cmd, result_queue)
    thread.start()

# print results as we get them
while threading.active_count() > 1 or not result_queue.empty():
    while not result_queue.empty():
        (cmd, output, status) = result_queue.get()
        print(cmd)
        print(output)
```

How can I run all of these commands at the same time achieving a result at the end? I am running in windows, pyhton 2.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first try didn't work because of the repeated definitions of stdout and sterror. Removing these definitions causes expected behavior.