# Python: Will a thread be killed after an exception is raised and not handled?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

The official documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) gives the following example:

```
def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        do_work(item)
        q.task_done()

q = Queue()
for i in range(num_worker_threads):
    t = Thread(target=worker)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

for item in source():
    q.put(item)

q.join()       # block until all tasks are done
```

I want to make sure all the threads are killed at this point before my main thread proceeds. I suppose after all the tasks in the queue have been processed, the q.get() method will raise an exception, which should kill the thread. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If there are no items in the queue, `get` will, by default, wait for items to be put into the queue. If you want it to raise an exception when there are no more items, either pass it `block=False` or use `get_nowait`.

Once you're using the non-blocking `get`, it should all work, but it is rather inelegant for your threads to die because of a raised exception in the normal case. I'd recommend surrounding it with a `try` block, and if it throws an exception due to the queue being empty, stop the thread cleanly:

```
try:
    item = q.get(block=False)
except queue.Empty:
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

if any of `do_work()`'s calls raise an exception then the thread that runs it will exit. Your main thread will *block forever* on `q.join()`  because `q.get()` hasn't been followed by `q.task_done()` in this case.

You could rewrite the example using a thread pool:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool # use threads

p = Pool(num_worker_threads)    
for _ in p.imap_unordered(do_work, source()):
    pass
p.close()
p.join() # no threads after this point
```

In this case, if `do_work()` raises an exception; it is propagated to the main thread and it exits (pool threads are daemonic so they do not keep the program running).

Another alternative to the `Queue`-based solution is to put sentinel values into the queue (one value per thread) and exit `worker()` if a sentinel is encountered, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9874484/4279):

```
STOP = object()

def worker(queue):
    for item in iter(queue.get, STOP): # until STOP is encountered
        do_work(item)

# instead of `q.join()`
for _ in threads: q.put(STOP)
for t in threads: t.join() # no threads after this point
```